# Is it not possible to change the font color in Beeware/toga?

Tags: python, beeware

I am trying to create a black background button with white text but there doesn't appear to be a parameter for font color anywhere in Beeware docs:

```
        login_input = toga.Button('SignIn',style=Pack(padding_top=25,background_color='#000000',font_size=20), on_press=self.login_handler)
```

The above code would just show a black button with invisible black text. The Pack style engine doesn't seem to support any font colors. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Toga follows CSS attribute names, so the foreground color attribute is just called [`color`](https://toga.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/style/pack.html#color).